# Create a audio wave scrubbable timeline. Swift 3 MacOS

Tags: xcode, macos, swift3

I am creating a MacOS application to take an audio file chosen by the user and display its sound waves in a timeline. Like the one below.

[image: Example of what I'm looking for.]

I have searched Google and Stack Overflow for a few hours and only found IOS examples. Every time I tried to take one and convert it to work with MacOS there were conflicting libraries used.

If you could provide me with some code to get started or a source/article that has information that would be great.

Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AudioKit can display waveforms using AKTableView.  It is cross platform and there's an example of how to load files into one on of the framework's playgrounds, which is also shown online here:

http://audiokit.io/playgrounds/Basics/Tables/

The code is simple so even if you need to add to it, you can pull the necessary parts from AudioKit and place it in your own project, if you don't want to add all of AudioKit to your project just for this one feature.